# Get the size of the window in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I Would like to determine the size of the browser window in Shiny to help me layout my plot divs better.  Specifically I would like to determine the aspect ratio of the window to see how many divs I should spread across the screen and it still look nice.  My initial thought would be that the number of plots would be `floor(width/(height-navbar_height))`.

I did some looking for this and I am currently unable to locate a possible solution and am currently lead to believe that this feature is simply not present in the clientData structure.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

See the example below. It uses Javascript to detect the browser window size (initial size and any resize), and use `Shiny.onInputChange` to send the data to the server code for processing. It uses `shiny:connected` event to get the initial window size, as `Shiny.onInputChange` is not ready for use until shiny is connected.

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

   # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         tags$head(tags$script('
                                var dimension = [0, 0];
                                $(document).on("shiny:connected", function(e) {
                                    dimension[0] = window.innerWidth;
                                    dimension[1] = window.innerHeight;
                                    Shiny.onInputChange("dimension", dimension);
                                });
                                $(window).resize(function(e) {
                                    dimension[0] = window.innerWidth;
                                    dimension[1] = window.innerHeight;
                                    Shiny.onInputChange("dimension", dimension);
                                });
                            ')),
         sliderInput("bins",
                     "Number of bins:",
                     min = 1,
                     max = 50,
                     value = 30)
      ),

      # Show a plot of the generated distribution
      mainPanel(
         verbatimTextOutput("dimension_display"),
         plotOutput("distPlot")
      )
   )
))

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
   output$dimension_display <- renderText({
       paste(input$dimension[1], input$dimension[2], input$dimension[2]/input$dimension[1])
   })

   output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
      # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
      x    <- faithful[, 2] 
      bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

      # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
      hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
   })
})

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  Sorry it took so long to check.  It seems though that there would be a better place to add this outside of the sidebarPanel.  For instance, right after the fluidPage call.

Comment: It does not matter where you add the Javascript though, as the Javascript will appear in the `head` section of the HTML regardless (as we used `tags$head`). You can verify the source code of the html page.

Comment: This javascript snippet gives me the following error:
"Warning: Error in if: argument is of length zero"

Answer (score 5):

There is a new and much simpler way to do this since 2021: using the {[shinybrowser](https://github.com/daattali/shinybrowser)} package. Example:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinybrowser::detect(),
  "Window size:",
  textOutput("size")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$size <- renderText({
    paste(
      shinybrowser::get_width(),
      "x",
      shinybrowser::get_height()
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Note that {shinybrowser} is currently on GitHub only and not yet on CRAN (should be in the near future). Note also that {shinybrowser} only gives you the **initial** dimensions, but will not update if the browser is resized.

Comment: Yes that's correct. The question did not mention if this needs to be re-calculated on browser resize or if just once. I'll add a comment to my answer to mention this drawback.

Comment: It's not yet, I want to get more people testing it before. But I did open a github issue based on this discussion to look into making the dimensions truly reactive

Answer (score -2):

Shorter version for getting window dimensions in shiny with `JS` from package `htmlwidgets`:

```
window_height <- JS('window.innerHeight')
window_width <- JS('window.innerWidth')
```

Comment: Please provide a MWE in Shiny.

Comment: This doesnt work for me besides, there is no working example