# R shiny: How to get square plot to use full width of panel?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a square plot (aspect ratio 1:1) that I'm trying to scale to be the full width of `mainPanel`. Due to the `height` parameter being `400px` by default, the plot comes out as a 400x400 image in the middle of the panel:

[image]

I read that you can alter the `height` parameter of `plotOutput` to be `"100%"` or `"auto"` to have the panel use the natural dimensions of the image. However, `plotOutput` then tries to retrieve the height parameter from `renderPlot`, which itself is getting its `height` value from `plotOutput` resulting in a "Catch-22" scenario and a plot of height `0px`.

What I'm trying to do is set the `height` value of `renderPlot` (or `plotOutput`) to be equal to the `width` of `mainPanel`, but I'm unsure how to access this value. Here's my code so far:

```
library( shiny )
library( ggplot2 )

server <- function(input, output)
{
    output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
        X <- data.frame( x=rnorm(input$n), y=rnorm( input$n ) )
        ggplot( X, aes(x=x, y=y) ) + geom_point() + coord_fixed()
    }, height=400   # how to get this value to be mainPanel width?
    )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout( 
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput("n", "Number of Samples", min=10, max=1000, value=100) ),
        mainPanel( plotOutput("plot1", height="auto") )
    )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Note from `?renderPlot` : "Note that, for height, using "auto" or "100%" generally will not work as expected, because of how height is computed with HTML/CSS."

Comment: Yea, I saw that. My understanding is that it's a reference to `renderPlot` and `plotOutput` using each other's `height` values under the `auto` setting, which can lead to unexpected results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36995142/get-the-size-of-the-window-in-shiny):

```
library( shiny )
library( ggplot2 )

server <- function(input, output)
{
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    X <- data.frame( x=rnorm(10), y=rnorm( 10) )
    ggplot( X, aes(x=x, y=y) ) + geom_point() +  coord_fixed()
    } ,
    height=reactive(ifelse(!is.null(input$innerWidth),input$innerWidth*3/5,0))
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout( 
    sidebarPanel(
      tags$head(tags$script('$(document).on("shiny:connected", function(e) {
                            Shiny.onInputChange("innerWidth", window.innerWidth);
                            });
                            $(window).resize(function(e) {
                            Shiny.onInputChange("innerWidth", window.innerWidth);
                            });
                            ')),
      sliderInput("n", "Number of Samples", min=10, max=1000, value=100) ),
    mainPanel( plotOutput("plot1"))
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```