# Shiny dynamic content based on window size (like css media query)

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny, reactive

I have some plots in a panel. I want to change them into `tabsetpanel` when the window width is small. Is there any way in shiny to determine window width of browser. For example, in the following example, how can I switch `uiOutput` from `plotPanel1` to `plotPanel2` when the window width is large enough.

```
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  title = "TestApp",
  h1("Test Application"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("bins", "Bins", 2, 20, 1, value = 10)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      fluidRow(
        uiOutput("plotPanel1")
      )
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    mdl <- lm(mpg ~ ., data = mtcars)
    ggplot(mdl, aes(.resid)) + geom_histogram(bins = input$bins)
  }, res = 110)
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    mdl <- lm(UrbanPop ~ ., data = USArrests)
    ggplot(mdl, aes(.resid)) + geom_histogram(bins = input$bins)
  }, res = 110)
  output$plot3 <- renderPlot({
    mdl <- lm(uptake ~ ., data = CO2)
    ggplot(mdl, aes(.resid)) + geom_histogram(bins = input$bins)
  }, res = 110)
  output$plotPanel1 <- renderUI({
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel(
        "plot1",
        plotOutput("plot1")
      ),
      tabPanel(
        "plot2",
        plotOutput("plot2")
      ),
      tabPanel(
        "plot3",
        plotOutput("plot3")
      )
    )
  })
  output$plotPanel2 <- renderUI({
    fluidRow(
      column(
        4,
        plotOutput("plot1")
      ),
      column(
        4,
        plotOutput("plot2")
      ),
      column(
        4,
        plotOutput("plot3")
      )
    )
  })
}

runApp(shinyApp(ui, server))
```

Answer (score 5):

Since `Shiny` is generating a bunch of HTML you could use `media-query`, or another possibility is to use `javaScript` and get the width of the window. I had some trouble with the `css` solution, but I will show you both:

### Approach #1 (Working): Using javaScript

With `javaScript` you can define an input element based on the `width` of the window:

```
  tags$head(tags$script('
                        var width = 0;
                        $(document).on("shiny:connected", function(e) {
                          width = window.innerWidth;
                          Shiny.onInputChange("width", width);
                        });
                        $(window).resize(function(e) {
                          width = window.innerWidth;
                          Shiny.onInputChange("width", width);
                        });
                        '))
```

If this script is included in the `UI`, you can then access `input$width` to obtain the width of the window. (Disclaimer: I used the accepted answer in the following [SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36995142/get-the-size-of-the-window-in-shiny) for the JS code.)

I added an `observer` to check the width. If it is below/above a certain threshold then the elements are shown/hidden.

```
  observe( {
    req(input$width)
    if(input$width < 800) {
      shinyjs::show("plotPanel1")
      shinyjs::hide("plotPanel2")
    } else {
      shinyjs::hide("plotPanel1")
      shinyjs::show("plotPanel2")
    }
  })
```

Full code:

```
library(shinyjs)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  title = "TestApp",
  h1("Test Application"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("bins", "Bins", 2, 20, 1, value = 10)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      fluidRow(
        div(id="p1", uiOutput("plotPanel1")),
        div(id="p2", uiOutput("plotPanel2"))
      )
    )
  ),
  tags$head(tags$script('
                        var width = 0;
                        $(document).on("shiny:connected", function(e) {
                          width = window.innerWidth;
                          Shiny.onInputChange("width", width);
                        });
                        $(window).resize(function(e) {
                          width = window.innerWidth;
                          Shiny.onInputChange("width", width);
                        });
                        '))
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  plot1 <- reactive({
    ggplot(lm(mpg ~ ., data = mtcars), aes(.resid)) +
      geom_histogram(bins = input$bins)
  }) 
  plot2 <- reactive({
    ggplot(lm(UrbanPop ~ ., data = USArrests), aes(.resid)) +
      geom_histogram(bins = input$bins)
  }) 
  plot3 <- reactive({
    ggplot(lm(uptake ~ ., data = CO2), aes(.resid)) +
      geom_histogram(bins = input$bins)
  })

  output$plotPanel1 <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel(
          "plot1",
          renderPlot(plot1())
        ),
        tabPanel(
          "plot2",
          renderPlot(plot2())
        ),
        tabPanel(
          "plot3",
          renderPlot(plot3())
        )
      )
    )
  })

  output$plotPanel2 <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      fluidRow(
        column(
          4,
          renderPlot(plot1())
        ),
        column(
          4,
          renderPlot(plot2())
        ),
        column(
          4,
          renderPlot(plot3())
        )
      ) 
    )  
  })

  observe( {
    req(input$width)
    if(input$width < 800) {
      shinyjs::show("plotPanel1")
      shinyjs::hide("plotPanel2")
    } else {
      shinyjs::hide("plotPanel1")
      shinyjs::show("plotPanel2")
    }
  })
}

runApp(shinyApp(ui, server))
```

This is not a perfect solution in my opinion, since we are rendering every plot twice, however you can probably build on this.

### Approach #2 (NOT working): CSS and media-query

You can control the `display` attribute within a `media-query` in `tags$head`. It works fine for any element, however I found that it doesn't work well with `UIOutput`.

Working example for simple `div` with `text`:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
      @media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
        #p1 {
          display: none;
        }

        #p2 {
          display: block;
        }
      }

      @media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
        #p1 {
          display: block;
        }

        #p2 {
          display: none;
        }
      }
      "
    ))
    ),
    div(id="p1", "First element"),
    div(id="p2", "Second element")
)
```

Not working example for `UIOutput`:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  title = "TestApp",
  h1("Test Application"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("bins", "Bins", 2, 20, 1, value = 10)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      fluidRow(
          div(id="p1", uiOutput("plotPanel1")),
          div(id="p2", uiOutput("plotPanel2"))
      )
    )
  ),
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
      @media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
        #plotPanel1 {
          display: none;
        }

        #plotPanel2 {
          display: block;
        }
      }

      @media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
        #plotPanel1 {
          display: block;
        }

        #plotPanel2 {
          display: none;
        }
      }
      "
    ))
    )
)
server <- function(input, output, session){
  plot1 <- reactive({
    ggplot(lm(mpg ~ ., data = mtcars), aes(.resid)) +
      geom_histogram(bins = input$bins)
  }) 
  plot2 <- reactive({
    ggplot(lm(UrbanPop ~ ., data = USArrests), aes(.resid)) +
      geom_histogram(bins = input$bins)
  }) 
  plot3 <- reactive({
    ggplot(lm(uptake ~ ., data = CO2), aes(.resid)) +
      geom_histogram(bins = input$bins)
  })

  output$plotPanel1 <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel(
          "plot1",
          renderPlot(plot1())
        ),
        tabPanel(
          "plot2",
          renderPlot(plot2())
        ),
        tabPanel(
          "plot3",
          renderPlot(plot3())
        )
      ) 
    )
  })
  output$plotPanel2 <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      fluidRow(
        column(
          4,
          renderPlot(plot1())
        ),
        column(
          4,
          renderPlot(plot2())
        ),
        column(
          4,
          renderPlot(plot3())
        )
      ) 
    )
  })
}

runApp(shinyApp(ui, server))
```

Comment: Note that instead of adding a bunch of custom javascript, you can now replace all the javascript with using the {[shinybrowser](https://github.com/daattali/shinybrowser)} package

Comment: Awesome, great job! @DeanAttali