# Access current position of UI elements

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to know if it is possible to access the current position (or alternativly width and height) of an UI element (in this case produced by uiOutput), so I know how much space is taken up by this and I can adjust the sizing of some other elements accordingly. This is what the basic setup looks like

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          "There is some more stuff here normally"
        ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
          uiOutput("ui_element"),
          plotOutput("plot")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$ui_element <- renderUI({
      "This is just some text to demonstrate. Usually there are some pictures embedded here as well,
      this is why it I use renderUI. I would like to know the position / size of this ui element"
      })
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
        plot(1:5,1:5)
    })
}
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I haven't found anything regarding this topic but maybe I am searching for the wrong things, so any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please provide us with a minimal reproducible example of your code. Furthermore, you might want to check [this](https://shiny.posit.co/r/articles/build/layout-guide/). There are serveral options to avoid sizing elements yourself.

Comment: I addes the example, although I am not sure, if this helps at all with the problem, since their is no error or anything to reproduce. I know about the other options but none of them are able to do what I want.

Comment: Maybe you can elaborate a little on what you are trying to achive? E.g. would you like to reduce the height of the plot once the uiOutput grows to fill the screen - or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a small change to the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36995142/get-the-size-of-the-window-in-shiny) you can get the size of the div rather than the window. You do need to write some javascript to get it to work

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$script('
      var dimension = [0, 0];
      $(document).on("shiny:connected", function(e) {
          const ele = document.getElementById("ui_element")
          dimension[0] = ele.getBoundingClientRect().width;
          dimension[1] = ele.getBoundingClientRect().height;
          Shiny.onInputChange("dimension", dimension);
      });
      $(window).resize(function(e) {
          const ele = document.getElementById("ui_element")
          dimension[0] = ele.getBoundingClientRect().width;
          dimension[1] = ele.getBoundingClientRect().height;
          Shiny.onInputChange("dimension", dimension);
      });
  ')),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      "There is some more stuff here normally"
    ),
    
    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("ui_element"),
      plotOutput("plot"),
      uiOutput("div_size")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$ui_element <- renderUI({
    "This is just some text to demonstrate. Usually there are some pictures embedded here as well,
      this is why it I use renderUI. I would like to know the position / size of this ui element"
  })
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plot(1:5,1:5)
  })
  output$div_size <- renderUI({
    paste(input$dimension, collapse=", ")
  })
}
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) This is exactly what I was looking for. I had read the other question but I didn't know, that this also allows accessing individual elements.